# LoggerFactory is not a Logback LoggerContext - SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder

Tags: java, spring-boot, microservices

I created a sample modular basic microservices (customer, fraud)using spring boot 3.0.4 with IntelliJ just to test auto service discovery pattern.  All was ok until I added a 3rd microservice: eureka server with the spring cloud dependencies (version 2022.0.1).

When I tried to run the application, I got the following error:

```
    SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: LoggerFactory is not a Logback LoggerContext but Logback is on the classpath. Either remove Logback or the competing implementation (class org.slf4j.helpers.NOPLoggerFactory loaded from file:/Users/apple/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.33/slf4j-api-1.7.33.jar). If you are using WebLogic you will need to add 'org.slf4j' to prefer-application-packages in WEB-INF/weblogic.xml: org.slf4j.helpers.NOPLoggerFactory
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.instanceCheckFailed(Assert.java:713)
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.isInstanceOf(Assert.java:632)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.getLoggerContext(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:382)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.beforeInitialize(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:123)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.onApplicationStartingEvent(LoggingApplicationListener.java:238)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(LoggingApplicationListener.java:220)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:172)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:165)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:127)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.multicastInitialEvent(EventPublishingRunListener.java:136)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.starting(EventPublishingRunListener.java:75)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.lambda$starting$0(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:54)
    at java.base/java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.doWithListeners(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:118)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.starting(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:54)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:302)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1304)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1293)
    at com.techronym.eurekaserver.EurekaServerApplication.main(EurekaServerApplication.java:11)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Here's my parent pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.techronym.app</groupId>
  <artifactId>demo-app</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <modules>
        <module>customer</module>
      <module>fraud</module>
      <module>eureka-server</module>
    </modules>

    <name>demo-app</name>
  <url>https://www.techronym.com</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
    <spring.boot.maven.plugin>3.0.4</spring.boot.maven.plugin>
    <spring.boot.dependencies.version>3.0.4</spring.boot.dependencies.version>
    <spring-cloud.version>2022.0.1</spring-cloud.version>

  </properties>

  <dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.boot.dependencies.version}</version>
        <scope>import</scope>
        <type>pom</type>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>

    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
      <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
      <version>1.18.24</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <pluginManagement><!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven defaults (maybe moved to parent pom) -->
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>${spring.boot.maven.plugin}</version>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
</project>
```

Eureka Server pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>demo-app</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.techronym.app</groupId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>eureka-server</artifactId>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-server</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

Eureka App:

```
package com.techronym.eurekaserver;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.server.EnableEurekaServer;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableEurekaServer
public class EurekaServerApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(EurekaServerApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Dependency tree

```
com.techronym.app:demo-app:pom:1.0-SNAPSHOT
+- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:jar:3.0.4:compile
 +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:3.0.4:compile
|  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:jar:3.0.4:compile
 |  |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:6.0.6:compile
|  |  |     +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:6.0.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:6.0.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:6.0.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:jar:3.0.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:jar:3.0.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.4.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.4.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-to-slf4j:jar:2.19.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:jar:2.19.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:jar:2.0.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- jakarta.annotation:jakarta.annotation-api:jar:2.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.33:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test:jar:3.0.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test-autoconfigure:jar:3.0.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path:jar:2.7.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- net.minidev:json-smart:jar:2.4.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- net.minidev:accessors-smart:jar:2.4.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     \- org.ow2.asm:asm:jar:9.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.33:compile
[INFO] |  +- jakarta.xml.bind:jakarta.xml.bind-api:jar:4.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- jakarta.activation:jakarta.activation-api:jar:2.1.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.assertj:assertj-core:jar:3.23.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy:jar:1.12.10:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest:jar:2.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:jar:5.9.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:jar:5.9.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.opentest4j:opentest4j:jar:1.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.junit.platform:junit-platform-commons:jar:1.9.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.apiguardian:apiguardian-api:jar:1.1.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-params:jar:5.9.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:jar:5.9.2:runtime
[INFO] |  |     \- org.junit.platform:junit-platform-engine:jar:1.9.2:runtime
[INFO] |  +- org.mockito:mockito-core:jar:4.8.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy-agent:jar:1.12.16:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.objenesis:objenesis:jar:3.2:runtime
[INFO] |  +- org.mockito:mockito-junit-jupiter:jar:4.8.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.skyscreamer:jsonassert:jar:1.5.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.vaadin.external.google:android-json:jar:0.0.20131108.vaadin1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:6.0.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-jcl:jar:6.0.6:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-test:jar:6.0.6:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.xmlunit:xmlunit-core:jar:2.9.1:compile
[INFO] \- org.projectlombok:lombok:jar:1.18.24:compile
[INFO] 
[INFO] ---------------------< com.techronym.app:customer >---------------------

[INFO] Building eureka-server 1.0-SNAPSHOT                                [4/4]
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ eureka-server ---
[INFO] com.techronym.app:eureka-server:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-server:jar:4.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter:jar:4.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-context:jar:4.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.springframework.security:spring-security-crypto:jar:6.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-commons:jar:4.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework.security:spring-security-rsa:jar:1.0.11.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- org.bouncycastle:bcpkix-jdk15on:jar:1.69:compile
[INFO] |  |        +- org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15on:jar:1.69:compile
[INFO] |  |        \- org.bouncycastle:bcutil-jdk15on:jar:1.69:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-server:jar:4.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:jar:3.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-json:jar:3.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jdk8:jar:2.14.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:jar:2.14.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-parameter-names:jar:2.14.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat:jar:3.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:jar:10.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-el:jar:10.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-websocket:jar:10.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:6.0.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:6.0.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:6.0.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:6.0.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:6.0.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator:jar:3.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure:jar:3.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-actuator:jar:3.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- io.micrometer:micrometer-observation:jar:1.10.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- io.micrometer:micrometer-commons:jar:1.10.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- io.micrometer:micrometer-core:jar:1.10.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     +- org.hdrhistogram:HdrHistogram:jar:2.1.12:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |     \- org.latencyutils:LatencyUtils:jar:2.0.3:runtime
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-freemarker:jar:3.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.freemarker:freemarker:jar:2.3.31:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-context-support:jar:6.0.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client:jar:4.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.netflix.eureka:eureka-client:jar:2.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- com.netflix.netflix-commons:netflix-eventbus:jar:0.3.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  |  +- com.netflix.netflix-commons:netflix-infix:jar:0.3.0:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  |  |  |  +- commons-jxpath:commons-jxpath:jar:1.3:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  |  |  |  +- joda-time:joda-time:jar:2.3:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  |  |  |  +- org.antlr:antlr-runtime:jar:3.4:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  |  |  |  |  +- org.antlr:stringtemplate:jar:3.2.1:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  |  |  |  |  \- antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.7:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  |  |  |  \- com.google.code.gson:gson:jar:2.1:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  |  |  \- org.apache.commons:commons-math:jar:2.2:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- com.thoughtworks.xstream:xstream:jar:1.4.19:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  |  \- io.github.x-stream:mxparser:jar:1.2.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  |     \- xmlpull:xmlpull:jar:1.1.3.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- com.netflix.servo:servo-core:jar:0.12.21:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  |  \- com.google.guava:guava:jar:19.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.5.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  |  \- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.4.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- commons-configuration:commons-configuration:jar:1.10:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  |  \- commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- org.codehaus.jettison:jettison:jar:1.4.0:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.apache.httpcomponents.client5:httpclient5:jar:5.1.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     +- org.apache.httpcomponents.core5:httpcore5:jar:5.1.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     +- org.apache.httpcomponents.core5:httpcore5-h2:jar:5.1.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     \- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.15:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.netflix.eureka:eureka-client-jersey3:jar:2.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.glassfish.jersey.connectors:jersey-apache-connector:jar:3.0.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.netflix.eureka:eureka-core-jersey3:jar:2.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- com.netflix.eureka:eureka-core:jar:2.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     \- jakarta.servlet:jakarta.servlet-api:jar:5.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.glassfish.jersey.containers:jersey-container-servlet:jar:3.1.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.glassfish.jersey.containers:jersey-container-servlet-core:jar:3.1.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-common:jar:3.1.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- org.glassfish.hk2:osgi-resource-locator:jar:1.0.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- jakarta.ws.rs:jakarta.ws.rs-api:jar:3.1.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-server:jar:3.1.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- jakarta.validation:jakarta.validation-api:jar:3.0.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-client:jar:3.1.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.glassfish.jersey.inject:jersey-hk2:jar:3.1.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.glassfish.hk2:hk2-locator:jar:3.0.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- org.glassfish.hk2.external:aopalliance-repackaged:jar:3.0.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- org.glassfish.hk2:hk2-utils:jar:3.0.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.28.0-GA:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.glassfish.hk2:spring-bridge:jar:3.0.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.glassfish.hk2:hk2-api:jar:3.0.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:5.2.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- jakarta.inject:jakarta.inject-api:jar:2.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-xml:jar:2.14.1:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.14.1:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.14.1:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.14.1:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- org.codehaus.woodstox:stax2-api:jar:4.2.1:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- com.fasterxml.woodstox:woodstox-core:jar:6.4.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-loadbalancer:jar:4.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-loadbalancer:jar:4.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- io.projectreactor:reactor-core:jar:3.5.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- org.reactivestreams:reactive-streams:jar:1.0.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- io.projectreactor.addons:reactor-extra:jar:3.5.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-cache:jar:3.0.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.stoyanr:evictor:jar:1.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-runtime:jar:4.0.1:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-core:jar:4.0.1:compile
[INFO] |        +- org.eclipse.angus:angus-activation:jar:1.0.0:runtime
[INFO] |        +- org.glassfish.jaxb:txw2:jar:4.0.1:compile
[INFO] |        \- com.sun.istack:istack-commons-runtime:jar:4.1.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:jar:3.0.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:3.0.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:jar:3.0.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:jar:3.0.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:jar:3.0.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.4.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.4.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-to-slf4j:jar:2.19.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:jar:2.19.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:jar:2.0.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- jakarta.annotation:jakarta.annotation-api:jar:2.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.33:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test:jar:3.0.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test-autoconfigure:jar:3.0.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path:jar:2.7.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- net.minidev:json-smart:jar:2.4.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- net.minidev:accessors-smart:jar:2.4.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     \- org.ow2.asm:asm:jar:9.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.33:compile
[INFO] |  +- jakarta.xml.bind:jakarta.xml.bind-api:jar:4.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- jakarta.activation:jakarta.activation-api:jar:2.1.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.assertj:assertj-core:jar:3.23.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy:jar:1.12.10:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest:jar:2.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:jar:5.9.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:jar:5.9.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.opentest4j:opentest4j:jar:1.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.junit.platform:junit-platform-commons:jar:1.9.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.apiguardian:apiguardian-api:jar:1.1.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-params:jar:5.9.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:jar:5.9.2:runtime
[INFO] |  |     \- org.junit.platform:junit-platform-engine:jar:1.9.2:runtime
[INFO] |  +- org.mockito:mockito-core:jar:4.8.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy-agent:jar:1.12.16:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.objenesis:objenesis:jar:3.2:runtime
[INFO] |  +- org.mockito:mockito-junit-jupiter:jar:4.8.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.skyscreamer:jsonassert:jar:1.5.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.vaadin.external.google:android-json:jar:0.0.20131108.vaadin1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:6.0.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-jcl:jar:6.0.6:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-test:jar:6.0.6:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.xmlunit:xmlunit-core:jar:2.9.1:compile
[INFO] \- org.projectlombok:lombok:jar:1.18.24:compile
```

Please what am I doing wrong?

Comment: i think i had a similar error before. inside some of the dependencies, they import other libraries that could conflict with each other. So you should ccheck each dependency and exclude the conflicting dependencies which in this case are Logback or slf4j

Comment: Thanks @experimentunit1998X but i did  review the dependency tree and i noticed the spring boot starter web had those dependencies and i excluded them yet it didnt work

Comment: No, i excluded and recompiled. i have also updated my question with a section of dependency tree

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got SLF4J 1.7 on the classpath and Spring Boot 3.0 requires SLF4J 2.0. I think the cause is your parent pom where the import of Boot's dependency management is incorrect. You're importing `spring-boot`:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.boot.dependencies.version}</version>
    <scope>import</scope>
    <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
```

It should be `spring-boot-dependencies`:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.boot.dependencies.version}</version>
    <scope>import</scope>
    <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I had a similar issue with another library conflict. The error message contains the full library name (in case of the OP: `slf4j-api-1.7.33.jar`, in my case it was a wiremock library).  In my case, the solution was to simply remove the dependency.